# How can I upload videos to Amazon S3 (for HLS Stream) and categorize them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming

I'm working on an app for on-demand HTTP Live video streaming using Amazon AWS. I was able to set up Amazon's default video-on-demand HLS workflow using the link below (i.e. video is uploaded, auto-encoded and stored in a different bucket with a unique ID).  I'm trying to find a way to automatically group videos by category (in DynamoDB or another database) when I upload them.  Has anyone done something similar before?  Do I need to use a Lambda function?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/video-on-demand/appendix-a.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI - in case anyone else is looking for a way to do this.  You can upload your video to AWS and use a javascript lambda function to automatically categorize them in a nosql database